# Precedent of country that did teaching reform: reducing number of tutors while increasing salaries for the rest

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if following question would be a right fit here,

I am looking for a Precedent of a country that would have done a school reform: from many teachers with minimal salaries to a fewer teachers with bigger salaries and how did it work out..

I have [asked this question on academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78399/precedent-of-country-or-large-institution-that-did-teaching-reform-reducing-n) and was wondering maybe here it would be a better fit...